# How can I read a binary string in C#?

Tags: c#, php, silverlight, post

There is a php script which sends a binary string to the client application:

```
$binary_string = pack('i',count($result_matrix));   
foreach ($result_matrix as $row)
{
    foreach ($row as $cell)
    {
        $binary_string .= pack('d',$cell);
    }
}
echo $binary_string;
```

Silverlight application receives $binary_string via POST protocol. How can I parse this binary string?

Or maybe there is a better way to send matrix from PHP to Silverlight?

Comment: What is "binary string" for you?

Comment: The binary numeral system, or base-2 number system, represents numeric values using two symbols, 0 and 1. Actually binary data could be represented by any base numeric system such as base-16 or base-8 becase there is conversion from bsae-2 to base-8 or base-16.

Comment: Both formats `i` and `d` have a machine dependent format and byte order/representation. So e.g. a php version compiled as 64bit will send different data than the same script running on a 32bit version of php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the data as `System.IO.Stream` type, you can directly use the method `read`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the elementary way is to send XML data? The reason is that on Silverlight side you have not only to unpack binary data, that packed with php function, but also have a knowlege how data sructure packed in php script represented in binary data.

If you will use HEX format for packing than use somethong like this to unpack data:

```
static byte[] UnpackHex(string hexvalue)
{
        if (hexvalue.Length % 2 != 0)
                hexvalue = "0" + hexvalue;
        int len = hexvalue.Length / 2;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
                string byteString = hexvalue.Substring(2 * i, 2);
                bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(byteString, 16);
        }
        return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the System.IO namespace you can also use the BinaryReader class. See documentation at this location [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.binaryreader%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

I think this should help. If you need more help, perhaps you should also provide some code from your silverlight side.